# Is it safe to pass JWTs to child React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Is this safe to do or is it dangerous.

```
  useEffect(() => {

   
    
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebase_user) {

        firebase_user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {

          setToken(idToken);
        });

      })

  },[]);


"<"Component jwt={token} /">"
```

Comment: What's the perceived danger here?  There's not enough information in the question understand what the problem is.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail how the token is actually being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not wrong, `JWTs` are not meant to protect the contents protected within them, as anyone with the `public key` can decrypt it (And the `public key` is available to anyone). What the `JWT` is doing is just to protect your backend server from malicious request, such that not anyone can randomly send request without being validated, that is if you validate your request to the server with the `JWT`. This is because not anyone can anyhow sign the `JWT` without the valid secret keys. So i guess it's fine to pass your `JWT` around in your react component.

Comment: I disagree. Without knowing what the component does with the JWT, we don't know if ti's being handled securely. There's not enough information in the question to know if this is actually "secure".  JWT are meant to be sent to backends, not frontend components.

Comment: Oh ok, however am i right to say that JWT is only meant to protect the backend?

Answer (score 1):

**It is completely safe to pass the JWT to child components.**

Passing a JWT around in your application through props does not expose it any more than storing it in a component's state, which you are already doing in your example. There is absolutely nothing wrong in passing your token to child components.

Comment: I disagree.  Without knowing what the component does with the JWT, we don't know if ti's being handled securely. There's not enough information in the question to know if this is actually "secure".    JWT are meant to be sent to backends, not frontend components.

Comment: @DougStevenson The question is just asking about sending the JWT to a child component through a prop, not whether the child component itself is handling the JWT safely, which is a separate question and would be impossible to answer without knowing the child component's code. As for your last sentence "JWT are meant to be sent to backends, not frontend components", I agree that JWTs are supposed to be sent to backends, but it's also fine to send them to whatever frontend components need them. What if the child component needed to make an API call that requires the JWT?

Comment: @DougStevenson the jwt is being passed to a child component to be used in an api call. Should I get the JWT again in the child component using the on auth state change function or should I pass it down.

Comment: I wouldn't try to deali with a JWT anywhere except where it's actually being used.  I also wouldn't store it in memory for an unspecified amount of time, since they expire after an hour.  Passing one around where it's not being used, and storing it in memory seems like unnecessary work, bug-prone, and possibly insecure.  Use the JWT only where you are absolutely certain how it's being used for a specific purpose.